How to deploy SvelteKit on your own server properly without interrupting the user?
So I created this information system with Sveltekit, Ubuntu 22.04 as the server OS, PM2 as the process manager and I'm running the app in Node.Js. I've read the Sveltekit documentation on how to build and deploy the app for node adapter and here's my svelte.config.js code:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

import path from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            out: 'build',
            precompress: false,
            envPrefix: '',
            polyfill: true
        }),
        // Disable CSRF
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false,
        },
        alias: {
            // these are the aliases and paths to them
            '$src': path.resolve('./src')
        }
    },
    vitePlugin: {
        inspector: false
    }
};

export default config;

After building it, all I need to do is submit the command npm run preview in order to run the app.
Since I'm using PM2, I created an ecosystem.config.cjs file so that I can run the app with PM2 command. Here's the configuration:
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "app_sistamu",
            script: "npm",
            args: "run preview -- --host --port 8080",
            watch: false,
            instances: "max",
            exec_mode: "cluster"
        },
        {
            name: "app_sistamu_DEV",
            script: "npm",
            args: "run dev -- --host --port 5173",
            out_file: "/dev/null",
            watch: false
        }
    ],
};

After all the preparation, all I have to do is merging everything from development branch to master branch. Here's what I do:
git merge -m "Merging branch development to master" development; npm install; npm run build; pm2 reload ecosystem.config.cjs --only app_sistamu

With this my application can now run on the server. There's just one thing. The next time if I want to make a changes, I need to rebuild the app and then reload the PM2. I mean yeah it makes sense because in order to deploy the app I need to build it again. But this causes a problem where during the build process, the app returns a 502 Bad Gateway error. But after everything is done, the app is back to normal again without any error.
This raises a question, how to deploy the app properly without disrupting user's interaction with the app?

Why would the app return a 502 during the build if you don't stop pm2 from serving it?

But if I stop pm2, that means the user can no longer access the app since I stop it, no?

Sure, but since you're not doing that right now, I don't see why you would get a 502 while building...

What I'm trying to say is how do I apply the changes without shutting down pm2 or at least not disrupting user interaction?

I understand you, but you're saying "during the build process, the app returns a 502 Bad Gateway error", and I'm trying to understand why (or for how long you're getting that) if you're not shutting down pm2 during the build. It of course takes a short moment for SvelteKit's vite preview to start up, but it should be only seconds...

Oh ok my bad for misunderstanding. Alright. So I need to shut down pm2 first, then run npm run build, after that I reload pm2? Is that it?

Ah, right, I think I kind of guess what's happening: npm run build probably cleans out the dist directory you're already serving – you'll probably want to npm run build --outDir=dist-new && mv dist dist-old-$RANDOM && mv dist-new dist or similar?

Yes that's it. Like I said that's why during building process, the app returns 502 error. I don't want to shut down pm2. That's why I'm asking this question how to avoid interrupting user while I'm applying any changes on my app

After a few attempts, I think I finally solved this problem. Thanks to a youtube video provided by auqust, here's how I solve it:

Before building the app, make sure you've installed adapter-node as per the documentation on your SvelteKit project. If so, run the build command to build the app, in this example run npm run build;
After done building the app, there should be a folder named "build". I then copied all the files inside it to a separate directory which is /var/www/production/. To copy all the files, simply run this command cp -a build/. /var/www/production/;
Open the target directory. Initialize the npm and then add "type"="module" in package.json file. Next, add express.js package by typing in npm install -D express;
Create a new file named server.js for serving the application later:

import express from "express";
import { handler } from "./handler.js";


const app  = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(handler);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The application is running on port ${port}`);
});


Since I'm using PM2 to run the app, I created an ecosystem.config.cjs file to run PM2:

module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name     : "app_sistamu",
            script   : "server.js",
            watch    : false,
            instances: "max",
            exec_mode: "cluster"
        }
    ],
};


To start PM2, I run this command pm2 start ecosystem.config.cjs --only app_sistamu.
By doing this the next time I have to apply new changes I simply run build command, paste the build files into the targeted directory, and then I reload the PM2 instances. This method gives zero downtime, meaning there's no interruption in user's end.
I hope this will help others in the future. If I did some mistake along the way or perhaps there's any other solution or approach, please comment down below here.

To make my comment an answer:
If you're doing

git merge -m "Merging branch development to master" development; npm install; npm run build; pm2 reload ecosystem.config.cjs --only app_sistamu

and you say the app is disrupted during the build, that probably means that npm run build is clearing out or even deleting the dist directory that npm run preview is serving.
With a deployment like that, you could probably build into another directory, then quickly swap the two to minimize the disruption:
# build into new directory
npm run build --outDir=dist-new
# move current dist out of the way
mkdir -p old-dist
mv dist old-dist/"$(date +%s)"
# move new directory into place
mv dist-new dist

Remember to clear out the old-dist directories, or they'll start piling up. :)

Ok thanks for clear things up. I'll give it a try and I'll update later


how to deploy the app properly without disrupting user's interaction with the app?

A very common solution is to

Use Docker containers

A typical workflow in this case is to break the building of the application and the deployment of the application to a two different parts.

Wrap your SvelteKit frontend application with node adapter (example) and run the node.js web server inside a Docker container
Build your Docker image using a Github Actions workflow (example)

Then on the production server.

Run a Docker command to update the running container to a new image. Docker will insta-swap the container to use a new image, and there are no interruptions.

docker pull frontend  # Pulls the new image to the local server cache
docker compose up -d frontend  # Switches to the new version 

This does not only apply to SvelteKit only, but any web server and web development today.
The downside this approach is that you need to learn how to use Docker first, and it is a lot to learn. However the Docker knowledge is reusable, and works for many different deployment workflows regardless of tools and industry.
